# Need help changing the color of the line and where it says "Other Commands" in VSCode when you press Ctrl + Shift + P

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is the image of the Command Palette:

[image: control palette category text color]

Comment: You want to change the color of the text `other commands` only in you example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to change the color of the text `other commands` in your Command Palette example, use this `colorCustomization`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
    "pickerGroup.foreground": "#ff0000"
}
```

inside of your `settings.json`.

`pickerGroup.foreground` : Quick picker (Quick Open) color for grouping labels.

from [Theme Colors reference: Quick Picker Colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#quick-picker-colors).  Also see this citation for general `workbench.colorCustomizations` info.

`other commands` is a label for the next group of entries in any quick pick panel so that `colorCustomization` will change the label for all quick pick panel, like `Ctrl+P` for example.